# Why does keywords in robotframework show Error Undefined keyword?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Why do keywords in robotframework show Error Undefined keyword? but other file don't show Error

[image: Screenshot of IDE with red underlines]

If I uninstall Robot Framework Language Server (Extension), In keyword file doesn't show Error

I want these errors to go away.

Comment: provide a [mre] and version info

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)